# ExampleData texts

Tags: curated-data

Im interested, what books, text are included the ExampleData, like Alice in Wonderland, The Raven... Is there any site, I can check all the text in mathematica? I tried for example Poe: The Black Cat, but its excluded. Is there any historical, political document, not only the Declaration of Independence?

Comment: Run `ExampleData["Text"]`